# Using an ADC with PIC24 and storing the data in an SD card

Tags: c, assembly, pic, adc

I'm just an engineer student and I have such a project. But I didn't find enough resources to read except the datasheets it seems like the PIC24 is not being used a lost in the industry and there is a big focus on PIC18 and PIC16.

So I'm looking for help or if there is way to compare it with other PIC because when I searched I found example for code for PIC18 but comparing it to the programming of PIC24 there is a big difference (I'm using Mplab X in my project).

microship provides some help but I'm looking for more information or projects or books, anything that help .

Comment: IMO, `PIC*` processors are a dying breed. Arduino, RPi, ESP32, STM32, Atmel, etc. are much better choices. PIC has non-linear banked memory. And, not very much of it. It should never be used in new designs. There are many SoC designs that can do whatever a PIC does, easier and better.

Comment: If you post your code, we can help more.  What part isn't working? SD Card or ADC?  E: Also, give MCC a try.  If you don't care about having control of drivers, MCC can take a lot of the heavy lifting off your shoulders.

Comment: @CraigEstey But you can't beat those prices =]

Comment: @Jason 15 extra minutes of my time dwarfs the savings ;-) But, for code, see OP's earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77572712/link-pic24-with-sdcard

Comment: From: [Was there any computer since about 1960 without interrupt support?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/28097/20865) there is a comment: Microchip still sell PICs however since Microchip bought Atmel they're also selling its rival AVR micros and AVR has basically taken over the PIC market with Arduinos being the gateway "drug" for the entire AVR family. – slebetman